# Setting a document selection to the standard Headings (+headings) or Body (+body) fonts with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I spent a bit of time looking for a solution to set the font at a given selection to "+Headings" as shown in the screenshot below. This is useful if one would later want to change the theme of the document and make sure that the font defined for Headings and Body are properly changed on the selection which font was programaticlaly changed.

[image: Font Drop down showng +headings and +body style fonts]

For instance, using `Selection.font.name = "Calibri"`, would set the font to "Calibri" but not have it set as "Calibri (Headings)"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this (setting to '+Headings' font) by using the following:

```
    Selection.Font.name = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1").Font.name
    Selection.Font.NameAscii = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1").Font.NameAscii
    Selection.Font.NameBi = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1").Font.NameBi
    Selection.Font.NameFarEast = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1").Font.NameFarEast
    Selection.Font.NameOther = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1").Font.NameOther
```

It seems that also using:

```
    Selection.Font.name = "Calibri"
    Selection.Font.NameAscii = "+headings"
```

To set the font to "+Body", one could use:

```
    Selection.Font.name = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal").Font.name
    Selection.Font.NameAscii = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal").Font.NameAscii
    Selection.Font.NameBi = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal").Font.NameBi
    Selection.Font.NameFarEast = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal").Font.NameFarEast
    Selection.Font.NameOther = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal").Font.NameOther
```

It seems that also using:

```
    Selection.Font.name = "Arial"
    Selection.Font.NameAscii = "+body"
```

NOTE: This assumes that you have not customized your 'Heading 1' or 'Normal' style to use a different font.

Comment: Or, better still, actually use the styles to format your document in the first place. It is impossible to format a document without using at least one style. By applying direct formatting, either via code or the UI, you are just layering formatting instructions on top of a style.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt 
I agree. By working around styles rather than using them, you are making things much more difficult for yourself and your users. You are adding to the underlying complexity of your document.

Comment: I agree with you. Unfortunately, there are some bugs in the Microsoft table styling options. Despite having set the style for the header row to use the +Headings font, it doesn't get applied (and somehow one cannot apply a style to the table headings. Sometimes one has to go around MS-Words weird behavior,  I could create a Table-Header style and apply this, I supose

Comment: Did you ever notice the issues with the Table styles not applying as it should? Such as font selected for headers/first column not being applied, or borders for table styles based on another table not being applied correctly? Perhaps should open another question on this.